# Is there any way to pause catching events in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

For example I want to catch a single 'scroll' event, and then pause listening until the handlers are been executed. I have been trying to solve this for couple of hours already with no success.

```
$('body').bind('wheel', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        console.log("up");
    }
    else{
        console.log("down");
    }
});
```

Edit: Added code example.

Comment: What about posting sample code??? BTW, if you write your code like your question, well...  ;)

Comment: I can post the code, wihich catches mousewheel events but wht is the point, if i have competly no  idea how to pause catching? I've tried, stopping event propagation, but it didnt worked, timeouts wount work too.

Comment: Post your scroll event binding. At least just how do you bind event to specific element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could switch a class on `body`:

```
$('body').addClass('wheel_disabled'); //removeClass('wheel_disabled');
```

And delegate your event:

```
$(document).bind('wheel', 'body:not(.wheel_disabled)', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
        console.log("up");
    } else {
        console.log("down");
    }
});
```